# Find all possible consecutive subset in a unsorted array using JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm

Say I have exactly 5 cards, and it is obviously unsorted, how could I find ***the length*** of all possible straight(s)? (Straight has at least length of 3)

Ace would be only considered as 1.

For example if I have a set of cards: A(spade) 3(heart) K(heart) 3(spade) 2(heart)

desired output would be: 3, 3

Another example if I have a set of cards: A(spade) 3(heart) A(club) 3(spade) 2(heart)

desired output would be: 3, 3, 3, 3

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problem are you facing? This seems like a homework question. [ask]

Comment: How are you arriving at those outputs? What have you tried?

Comment: @Scott.D is what I've done what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in the length of all possible straights you can use your combinatorics knowledge.

You have 5 cards. Let's represent them with numbers. You'll change it to `Card`s yourself:

```
int[] filter = new int[13];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    filter[cards[i]]++;
}

int j = 0;
while (j < 13) {
    if (filter[j] > 0) {
        int length = 0;
        while (filter[j] > 0) {
            length++;
            j++;
        }
        if (length == 3) {
            for (int k = 0; k < filter[j - 1] * filter[j - 2] * filter[j - 3]; k++) {
                System.out.print(3 + " ");
            }
        }
        if (length == 4) {
            for (int k = 0; k < filter[j-1] * filter[j - 2] * filter[j - 3] * filter[j - 4]; k++) {
                System.out.print(4 + " ");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < filter[j-1] * filter[j - 2] * filter[j - 3]; k++) {
                System.out.print(3 + " ");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < filter[j - 2] * filter[j - 3] * filter[j - 4]; k++) {
                System.out.print(3 + " ");
            }
        }
        if (length == 5) {
            System.out.println("5 4 4 3 3 3");
        }
    }
    j++;
}
```

The idea of the algorithm is:

1. Make a filter in which, each cell will say how many cards of rank `i` you have.
2. Search for the longest sequence of cards that can make a straight. You can only have one with appropriate length.
3. Depending of the length of the sequence and the number of appearances of each card print the length of each straight.

**Example**:

`cards = {1, 2, 2, 3, 4];`
`filter = {0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0...}`

length is 4, so let's see how many times we can take straight of length 4. The answer is `1*2*1*1`. How many times can we take a straight of length 3? `1*2*1 + 2*1*1`.

If it was to be extended for general usage, the only thing to be changed is the printing. Instead of three `if`s, there would be a need of a loop which would loop for each length of straight that's accepted and for each starting card.

```
for (int l = length; l > minLength; l--) {
    int amount = 1;
    for (int m = 0; m < length - l + 1; m++) { //there might be by 1 mistake
        amount *= filter[j - m - 1];
    }
    for (int m = 0; m < amount; m++) {
        System.out.print(l + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: thanks man, I haven't checked this question as I figured out just after my post. But anyway, thank you!